# How to resize Android Sutdio using wmctrl?

Tags: resize, android-studio, wmctrl

`wmctrl` works for other windows, but for android studio, it doesn't work for me. Upon investigation, I found the tile of the window as seen by `window.get_active_title()` is, FocusProxy.

I tried the following commands :

`wmctrl -r "FocusProxy" -e 0,59,52,1428,1028`

`wmctrl -r "Android Studio" -e 0,59,52,1428,1028`

Comment: Your second command works here. What is the window title?

Comment: @JacobVlijm The Window Title as visible on the screen is `SampleApp -[~/SampleApp] - [app] - ~/SampleApp/app/src/main/java/mycompany/file.java - Android Studio 2.1.1` But when I inspect it using python's `window.get_active_title()` and `window.get_active_class()` I get `FocusProxy` as title and class as `Focus-Proxy-Window.FocusProxy`

Comment: @JacobVlijm any update?